# Clean JSON from Mongo document in Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have never worked with MongoDB in Java before, so I was surprised to see a data structure like this:

```
Person:
  - name: String
  - age: Number
  - lastLogin: Date
```

Get rendered like this when doing `toString()` to get the JSON view:

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "age": {
        "$numberLong": 25
    },
    "lastLogin": {
        "$date": //TS HERE
    }
}
```

I could write a recursive algorithm to rewrite that, but I'm guessing that there is a more elegant way of handling this. I don't want an ORM or anything like that that goes against a POJO. Just a clean `java.util.Map` or something like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: it's not verry clear, can you add the problematic code please? On what are tou calling `toString()`?

Comment: `toString()` returns `JSON` representation. `BasicDBObject`and `org.bson.Document` already are `java.util.Map`.